# Package a COM Ole Oject Library with database in C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, windows

I'm developing a Sql database module in C# and It's my first project in C# so it's really confused.
Now I exported to a dll file and have to registered it and create database by script manually. So are there any method that I can package it into a installation file that auto register object and create database? I've search but it only have a option publish in visual studio with Application, Not a Library.

Extra Question: I'm using visual studio 2015. My database is just local database and I read somewhere that Visual Studio have a local database format is SQL CE. But I find only template that create mdf database, and I think it's new local database format, isn't it?. I try to attach this file to Sql Management Studio in remote machine, but it seem like that this mdf file have some static link to my development computer path and it can't be attached. I've to switch to Server database, which is created from another SQL project and generate script to create database. So are there any method that I can deploy local database without script file? And is it that connect String is the same for all version?
My database is small So if it need to convert to other format, I think I could try.

Comment: The visual studio one click install might have the ability to register com servers, you may want to search for that. However, if you want to take full control of the install with the ability to easily register (during install) and  unregister (during uninstall) your com components without much effort then you might want to take a look at InstallShied.

Comment: For the Database question, when you install your database file, your end user should be able to choose a destination drive and folder etc. You will have to update your connection from a hardcoded value to your <INSTALLDIRECTORY>/Data/datafile or whatever.

Comment: Hi @RossBush, Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi @RossBush, Thanks for your reply. I checked One Click Install but is seem like only publish an executable project. I hope that there's a way that create installation file but only register the dll library and create database. Is it possible?

Comment: You can create a new onclick install project and set the .ocx or com .dll as a support file to be copied to the installation directory. I don't know if you can execute code from a one-click install, however, I think you can execute a file, so to register your com object you might be able to create a .bat file with a regsrv32 command.